# doing a post from HTML anchor

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to have post request if i click on html anchor instead of linkbutton?

Is anchor exclusively used for get requests and there is no way around it?  Is there any trick ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LinkButton` just uses a snippet of (messy, inline) JavaScript on an anchor to POST the page by calling the ASP.Net client method `__doPostBack()`. You can replicate this behavior by:

1. writing your own script to POST the page (keep in mind this may cause problems with validators)
2. writing your own script to call `__doPostBack()`
3. [using a server method to generate the script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx)

Comment: could you explain #2 little more?

Comment: @user2844121 - Take a look at [this article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack()_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx). It shows you how to call `__doPostBack` from your own script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can submit you form on the click of anchor link.
For this you must need to you javascript or jQuery.

Working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#formname').submit();
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formname" action="p.php"> // use you asp page
<input type="text" />
</form>
<a id="submit" href="javscript:void(0);"> Submit </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```